# In Selenium, how do I return all Options in a Select Element that contain Data Dividers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

I need to return all selectable options in my dropdown. Usually, I use my method

```
        public static List<string> SelElemListItemTxtToListString(SelectElement elem)
    {
        return elem.Options.Select(p => p.GetAttribute("textContent")).ToList();
    }
```

However this is not working for a new custom dropdown in my application. This dropdown includes Options that are "data dividers". Basically they can not be seen on the UI and can not be selected, but they appear as Option tags

```
<option data-divider="true"></option>
```

So as you would imagine, the method above returns these. How do I filter these out?

Note that all other Options that I would want to be returned are as follows

```
<option value="f2025aab-1b47-415a-876f-e93fbe8d2bdf" style="" title="Late Night - Week Day">Late Night - Week Day</option>
<option value="1467df26-b32e-4c90-9ed1-3dcf27dd1830" style="font-weight: bold !important;" title="Late Night">Late Night</option>
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and clarify your question. The question itself states that you want to return `OPTION`s that contain `data-divider` but in the question you apparently have other `OPTION`s that you want returned. Please post the HTML of the entire `SELECT` and clearly indicate what you want returned, etc.

Comment: On top of JeffC's good comment, also add the locator you are using - the problem has two solutions - filtering out in C# logic, or at locator level (which might be a tiny bit faster).